# Mysql query to get data by latest date and time

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains two columns names Date and Time.Date column has dataype of `DATETIME` and time has `varchar`.Now as per my requirement i have to get the data by latest Date and latest time .For Example

```
2014-09-12  10:00
2014-09-12  12:00
2014-09-12  16:00
2014-09-19  10:00
2014-09-19  12:00
2014-09-19  16:00
```

I want data to be fetched like ..

```
2014-09-19  16:00
2014-09-19  12:00    
2014-09-19  10:00
2014-09-12  16:00
2014-09-12  12:00
2014-09-12  10:00
```

Here is the query that i am using but data regarding time order is not maintained.

```
select date as Date,time as Time from table ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Please help me with this..
Thanks  in advance..

Comment: `SELECT date as Date,time as Time FROM table ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if date and time are two different columns then try this query

```
select date as Date,time as Time from table ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat both fields and make order bid concatenated field, see below

```
select date as Date,time as Time from table 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', `date`, `time`), "%Y-%m%d %H:%i:%s") DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

select date as Date,time as Time from table ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC;

If you want to sort by two columns, use two columns